# Sending Latlng from CustomAdapter to MapActivity using intent

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent

I have a listview in MainActivity which has OnItemClickListener method that calls the MapActivity. The Map Activity gets the latitude and longitude from the CustomAdapter (JSON). The goal is when click on one of the items in the list it opens the MapActivity and get the latitude and longitude from the CustomAdapter.  My problem now is that the MapActivity starts directly without clicking on the items.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

// resturants json url
private static final String url = "http://w99ltestapp.w99l.net/w99ltestapp/webservice/?link=getRest";
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private List<Resturant> resturantList = new ArrayList<Resturant>();
private ListView listView;
private CustomListAdapter adapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, resturantList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }});
```

CustomAdapter

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Resturant> resturantItems;


    ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

    public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Resturant> resturantItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.resturantItems = resturantItems;   }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return resturantItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return resturantItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.image);
    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView lat = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lat);
    TextView lng = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lng);


    // getting resturant data for the row
    Resturant m = resturantItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getImage(), imageLoader);

    // name
    name.setText(m.getName());

    // SETTING UP AND SENDING DATA
    lat.setText("Lat: " + String.valueOf(m.getLat()));

    lng.setText("Lng: " + String.valueOf(m.getLng()));

    double latitude = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(m.getLat()));
    double longitude = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(m.getLng()));

    LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(latitude, longitude );
    //LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(11.145315551, 99.333455333);


    Intent intent= new Intent(convertView.getContext(), MapsActivity.class);

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("from_position", fromPosition);
    //args.putParcelable("to_position", toPosition);

    intent.putExtra("bundle", args);

    convertView.getContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```

MapsActivity

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private LatLng fromPosition= new LatLng(-34,151) ;
// private  LatLng toPosition ;
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");
    fromPosition = bundle.getParcelable("from_position");
    toPosition = bundle.getParcelable("to_position");
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney =fromPosition;
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("resturant"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why bother with passing data into intent, You can use static variable for access to anywhere in application. You also can adjust you intent as per your requirements.

Just use fromPosition as below,

public static LatLng fromPosition;

Comment: what if I use firebase databse to store the LatLong data along with other data like name ect.

Answer (score 2):

**Pass the data this way from CustomListAdapter**

```
 @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
someView.setOnClikListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final int position = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MapsActivity.class);
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                //Add your data from getFactualResults method to bundle
                bundle.putString("from_position", your start point);
                bundle.putString("to_position", your end point);
                //Add the bundle to the intent
                intent.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(intent);));
            }
        });
 }
```

**get data in MapsActivity this way**

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

//Extract the data…
fromPosition = bundle.getString("from_position");  
toPosition = bundle.getString("to_position");
```

Comment: I want to pass the data to MainActivity from CustomAdapter first. Then pass them to MapActivity from MainActivity

Comment: write setOnClikListener in getView() method on any view.
Like @Override
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     someView.setOnClikListener(new MyOnClickListener(context, itemName));

 }